# Mounty did not work properly after upgrading to Monterey

Tags: permission, mount, monterey

When I use Mac OS Big Sur I used Mounty to make NTFS external drivers writable. But After upgrading to Monterey it does not work as expected.

There is no issue or error message in the UI, it shows a successfully mounted message after I click the remount button and open the external hard disk with another finder window. But I could not have written permission on it as expected.

I even tried to reinstall it but it does not work and even searching could not find a better solution. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounty doesn't work on macOS Monterey...yet.

The [Mounty webpage](https://mounty.app) says:

> Attention: macOS Monterey seems to be not compatible with current version, I will work to fix this. Please follow me on Twitter @uwehollatz to get notified when it is ready.